# Implications of proof of abc conjecture for cs theory

Tags: big-picture, nt.number-theory

What implications would a proof of the [abc conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture) have for tcs?

http://quomodocumque.wordpress.com/2012/09/03/mochizuki-on-abc/

Comment: see also [proof claimed for connection between primes](http://www.nature.com/news/proof-claimed-for-deep-connection-between-primes-1.11378) by Ball, Nature

Comment: high voted post with bkg/analysis/papers/links, mathoverflow, [philosophy behind mochizuki's work"](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106560/philosophy-behind-mochizukis-work-on-the-abc-conjecture)

Comment: [polymath resources on the Mochizuki attack](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=ABC_conjecture), generally frequently updated. links to Mochizukis papers, recent discussions, (MSM) media coverage etc

Answer (score 25):

[Bhatnagar, Gopalan, and Lipton](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/people/home/parik/RESEARCH/jcss.pdf) show that, assuming the abc conjecture, there are polynomials of degree $O((kn)^{1/2+\varepsilon})$ representing the Threshold-of-$k$ function over ${\mathbb Z}_6$. For fixed constant $k$, and $m$ which has $t$ prime factors, the abc conjecture implies a polynomial for Threshold-of-$k$ over $\mathbb Z_m$ with degree $O(n^{1/t+\varepsilon})$.

This presumably has relevance to the ${\sf TC^0}$ versus $\sf ACC^0[6]$ problem.

Answer (score 22):

this paper points out that computing the reciprocal square root value using floating point representation is widespread in CS applications ("very common in scientific computations"); the authors show that a more efficient formula is possible for computing the correctly rounded value if the ABC conjecture holds.

[1] [The abc conjecture and correctly rounded reciprocal square roots](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.103.6358&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
 Ernie Croot, Ren-Cang Li, Hui June Zhu, Elsevier TCS 2004

[2] [fast inverse square root calculation, wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)